# Number of color on an STN screen

Tags: lcd, stn

I would like to understand how can I determine the number of color of a STN screen.

For a TFT screen it is simple if I have 6R-6G-6B screen it is 262144 color, if it is 8R-8G-8B it is 16million colors. I just have to do the 2^n with n the number of bit.

But on STN there is usually 4 or 8 bits driven in the LCD. But if I understood well the functionment of this type of screen each bit is latch on 1 segment. Then with 8 bits you drive 8 segments so 2 and 2/3 pixel which for me mean that each segment can only be either on or off then you just have 8 color possible for a pixel. But I saw some description with STN of 4096 colors, how is that possible? 
I think I missed something in the operation mode of a STN screen.

Is it a mater of duty cycle? How do I determine a number of color for a STN screen?

Answer (score 1):

Could be duty cycle, also could be aggregating pixels.  For example, if you were to place 3x8 color pixels in close vicinity (or stack them or something else like that), you could blend their colors in such a way that you could get 8^3 colors, or, 4096 colors.

Comment: That's called "[color dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither#Digital_photography_and_image_processing)".

Comment: I also learned something but I do not think dithering is the technology used in STN